# WPF - programmatically referencing image resource in codebehind of Window with no XAML

Tags: wpf, image, inheritance, window

Consider a class that inherits from `System.Windows.Window` like so:

```
Public Class MyWindow
    Inherits Window

    Private _root As Grid

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

        _root = New Grid
        Me.AddChild(_root)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Me_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded

        Dim image As New Image
        Dim bitmapImage As New BitmapImage(New Uri("Assets/MyImage.png", UriKind.Relative))
        image.Source = bitmapImage
        image.Width = 100
        image.Height = 100
        image.Stretch = Stretch.Fill

        _root.Children.Add(image)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Let it be part of a WPF Windows Application that has the following module as its startup object:

```
Module MyModule

    Sub main()

        Dim myApplication As New Application
        myApplication.Run(New MyWindow)

    End Sub

End Module
```

The window gets displayed, but the image does not. When inserting the exact same image loading code in the `Loaded` event of a VS default `MainWindow` class (MainWindow.xaml.vb), the image shows up as expected. `MyImage.png` has 'Build Action' set to 'Resource' in both cases. What am I missing here?

**Edit**:

I learned that such references in codebehind must be specified using the Pack URI scheme, so replacing the `Uri` code with

```
New Uri("pack://application:,,,/Assets/MyImage.png")
```

will make it work. The problem was that the relative `Uri` was interpreted as 'file system absolute' (despite having specified `UriKind.Relative`), and the image location got resolved to `C:\Assets\MyImage.png`.

But that doesn't answer the underlying question: Why does

```
New Uri("Assets/MyImage.png", UriKind.Relative)
```

work when used in the codebehind of the standard `MainWindow` class (which also inherits `Window`, but additionally has some associated XAML), but not in a 'bareboned' descendant of `Window` like the `MyWindow` class above (defined in code only)?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the output Window if it cannot find the Uri path you gave?

Comment: Actually, I am. Now. Which is weird, because I did attach an ImageFailed event to it earlier to test, but got nothing. The problem was that it couldn't find the image because it was interpreting the Uri as absolute (even though I specified it as relative). The solution was to use `New Uri("pack://application:,,,/Assets/MyImage.png")`

Comment: Are you for effin real? Yes, I have a very good idea what I'm talking about. You don't. This is not your average business application. And I'm not talking about "dynamic" as in "dynamically linked to data". This is a modular development framework, where new features are added as plugins (some of which are new user interface components). By "dynamic" I meant that it is a tool for building applications. Much like .Net itself operates in order to allow YOU to play around with your MVVM paradigm. Sit down.

Comment: As a footnote - If you are able to do stuff like this with MVVM, please let me know: martinwardener.com/adzinoux

Comment: @d7samurai Ok. my props to you for that. I'll edit the question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the Uri was interpreted as absolute - even though I specified it as UriKind.Relative.

When replacing with

```
Dim bitmapImage As New BitmapImage(New Uri("pack://application:,,,/Assets/MyImage.png"))
```

it works.